# unable to understand Typescript union type never type property

Tags: typescript

```
    type data1={x:string, q?:never, y:string}

    type data2={p:string, q:boolean, r:number}

    type data3= data1|data2 

let v1:data3={x:"tree", y:"flower", r:45}        //OK

let v2:data3={p:"sigma",q:true,r:100, x:"tree"}   // ERROR
```

my doubt is why v1 is OK even it contains excess property r , but at v2 i am getting error at the excess property x ?

Comment: See the linked q/a and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863 for more information. Non-discriminated unions don't undergo excess property checking when the property key in question exists on at least one union member. People generally don't like this, but that's how it works. The other answer provides details.

Comment: @jclaz  why it is performing excess property checking at v2 only  ,but not at v1 ?

Comment: because `q` is a discriminant property (`undefined` vs `true` or `false`).